# Передача массива из php в js (json)

Tags: php, javascript, sql, json

Есть репликация `Asterisk(master)+Apache(slave)`.
На стороне `Apache` создал веб-интерфейс, показывающий результат выборки по базе.
Для этой выборки нужна гистограмма. Но `JS`-гистограмма берет данные из забитых в файл значений. `DATE COUNT TIME`. Как мне передать массив (поле `COUNT`) в `"data" JS`?

```js
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
      ${demo.css}
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function () {
        $('#container').highcharts({
          chart: {
            type: 'column'
          },
          title: {
            text: 'Monthly Average Rainfall'
          },
          subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
          },
          xAxis: {
            categories: [
              '9.00',
              '10.00',
              '11.00',
              '12.00',
              '13.00',
              '14.00',
              '15.00',
              '16.00',
              '17.00',
              '18.00',
            ],
            crosshair: true
          },
          yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
              text: 'COUNT'
            }
          },
          tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
            pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
                '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} mm</b></td></tr>',
            footerFormat: '</table>',
            shared: true,
            useHTML: true
          },
          plotOptions: {
            column: {
              pointPadding: 0.2,
              borderWidth: 0
            }
          },
          series: [{
            name: 'DATE',
            data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1]

          }]
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

    <div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Код который будет вызываться в JS файле чтобы получить ответ от сервера где вы должны указать HTTP путь к файлу с кодом **PHP** указанным ниже.

```
$.ajax({
    url: url.to.php.file,
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
    // тут пишите данные в виде массива по которым нужно отфильтровать, что-то...
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    json: true
}).done(function(data){
    console.log(data);
}).always(function(dataError){
    console.log(dataError);
});
```

**Код PHP который отдаст вам JSON**

```
<?php
    // тут пишите основной код запроса к базе данных и потом его вставляете в виде массива в переменную $resultJson
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    $resultJson = array("text" => "Hello!");
    echo json_encode($resultJson);
?>
```

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, где на примере моих файлов использовать данные Вами строки кода? Где и как? Я немного не понял:
1. Код запроса к БД будет писаться все равно через создание новой переменной для "описания" данного запроса. 
2. Куда именно вставить JS-код?
Я понимаю задачу-нужно выполнить запрос, который из 20ти колонок таблицы сделает 3 колонки, и уже из результата, из этих трех колонок, JS должна получить массив колонки COUNT, который будет выглядеть как:
data: {
    COUNT1, COUNT2, COUNT3, COUNT4
    },

Comment: Ну так и получайте себе массив колонки COUNT не пойму в чем у Вас проблема, jQuery или JavaScript это спокойно позволяют делать, если Вы пишите такие достаточно сложные скрипты, то $.each(); Вы должны знать.